# C# generated code to be displayed in WebBrowser

Tags: c#

I have a **Windows Form** program that will generate HTML code dynamically and a WebBrowser will display the generated code.

Is it the only way, to save a temp HTML file, then display it in thw WebBrowser? Is there a way that I don't need to save and display instantly in the WebBrowser?

Comment: In WPF, you can do a WebBrowser.NavigateToString().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use the WebBrowser.DocumentStream property like this:

```
var myHTMLString = "<html><body><h1>Hello!</h1></body></html>";

// Convert your html string into a byte array
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myHTMLString);

// Create a MemoryStream from the byte array
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);

// Assign the new MemoryStream to the web browser
myWebBrowser.DocumentStream = ms;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: can you try to explain the code, because I am a newbie. what does ms.write do? Why(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)?

Comment: @DanielCheung http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.write.aspx

Comment: Ok. I've simplified the solution a bit. Basically you just convert your string to a byte array that can be stored in a MemoryStream object. After you have your memorystream, simply assign it to the myWebBrowser.DocumentStream property.